# for cycle and RegExp

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, for-loop

So i was trying to do a function to convert a message into an emoji with regular expressions. Then i made this function but it doesnt work. Any tip?

HTML

```
<span class="message-text">:D</span>
```

Javascript

```
function check() {
        var allreg ={
            "/:D/": "'<img width='32px' height='32px' src='http://emojipedia-us.s3.amazonaws.com/cache/18/2f/182fa3786046d170707fa46a257185cb.png'>'",
            "/:C/": "'<img width='32px' height='32px' src='http://emojipedia-us.s3.amazonaws.com/cache/c5/a5/c5a5a52fa1633e19ab2648f23ab1ee37.png'>'",
            "/8+[)]/": "'<img width='32px' height='32px' src='http://emojipedia-us.s3.amazonaws.com/cache/c1/2c/c12c7f3797ed8fcdcbedffb2649abfb1.png'>'",
            "/:O/": "'<img width='32px' height='32px' src='http://emojipedia-us.s3.amazonaws.com/cache/55/af/55af488f029266842c13a54d4c50fc11.png'>'",
            "/:+[)]/": "'<img width='32px' height='32px' src='http://emojipedia-us.s3.amazonaws.com/cache/be/22/be22105632cfc32abf7b24bed3924e12.png'>'",
            "/._./": "'<img width='32px' height='32px' src='http://emojipedia-us.s3.amazonaws.com/cache/ce/1a/ce1a33d6a4535ce73c8b2b899d51071b.png'>'",
            "/:heart:/": "'<img width='32px' height='32px' src='http://emojipedia-us.s3.amazonaws.com/cache/3e/f0/3ef0aeaf797844b672df6198c53ba479.png'>'",
            "/:P/": "'<img width='32px' height='32px' src='http://emojipedia-us.s3.amazonaws.com/cache/43/be/43be98eee74f44eddec9c3137b1edf28.png'>'",
            "/;P/": "'<img width='32px' height='32px' src='http://emojipedia-us.s3.amazonaws.com/cache/7e/d5/7ed517c9f335c3171b6f92685514667a.png'>'",
            "/;+[)]/": "'<img width='32px' height='32px' src='http://emojipedia-us.s3.amazonaws.com/cache/58/be/58be1ae13dbf3fb471f7f598a0365734.png'>'",
            "/:+[(]/": "'<img width='32px' height='32px' src='http://emojipedia-us.s3.amazonaws.com/cache/0c/04/0c04f9fd77dc486724c269587028e7d2.png'>'",
            "/.-./": "'<img width='32px' height='32px' src='http://emojipedia-us.s3.amazonaws.com/cache/e6/7c/e67c860bd5cd2b9b443516171ec3c6a3.png'>'",
            "/-.-/": "'<img width='32px' height='32px' src='http://emojipedia-us.s3.amazonaws.com/cache/c1/05/c105ab901e2fa6e67b38879bcc0ac0b0.png'>'",
            "/:pepe:/": "'<img width='32px' height='32px' src='https://i.imgur.com/OE9Jb7b.png'>'"
        }
        var emval = [':D',':C','8)',':O',':)','._.',':heart:',':P',';P',';)',':(','.-.','-.-',':pepe:'];
        for(var emoticon in allreg){
        var result = new RegExp(emoticon,'g'); 
        for(var i=0;i<=13;i++){
         $(".message-text:contains('"+emval[i]+"')").html(function (_,html) {
            return html.replace(result,allreg[emoticon]);
            });
           }
        }
    }
    check();
```

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly doesn't work?

Comment: let's say i have a span with the class message-text. if the span got any of the characters on the emval list it should call the replace method to change the text to the respective image

Comment: Let's say you show, in the question itself, the code you've already got (including HTML), maybe in the form of a [mcve]...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) constructor creates a regular expression object for
>   matching text with a pattern.

in the constructor you have to pass the text of the regular expression.

```
new RegExp(":D",'g')
```

The keys of allreg object doesn't need slashes because you break the regex .

```
 var allreg ={ ':D': "'<img width='32px' height='32px' src='http://emojipedia-us.s3.amazonaws.com/cache/18/2f/182fa3786046d170707fa46a257185cb.png'>'"}
```

```js
function checkemoji() {
            var allreg ={
                ':D': "'<img width='32px' height='32px' src='http://emojipedia-us.s3.amazonaws.com/cache/18/2f/182fa3786046d170707fa46a257185cb.png'>'",
                ':C': "'<img width='32px' height='32px' src='http://emojipedia-us.s3.amazonaws.com/cache/c5/a5/c5a5a52fa1633e19ab2648f23ab1ee37.png'>'",
                '8+[)]': "'<img width='32px' height='32px' src='http://emojipedia-us.s3.amazonaws.com/cache/c1/2c/c12c7f3797ed8fcdcbedffb2649abfb1.png'>'",
                ':O': "'<img width='32px' height='32px' src='http://emojipedia-us.s3.amazonaws.com/cache/55/af/55af488f029266842c13a54d4c50fc11.png'>'",
                ':+[)]': "'<img width='32px' height='32px' src='http://emojipedia-us.s3.amazonaws.com/cache/be/22/be22105632cfc32abf7b24bed3924e12.png'>'",
                '._.': "'<img width='32px' height='32px' src='http://emojipedia-us.s3.amazonaws.com/cache/ce/1a/ce1a33d6a4535ce73c8b2b899d51071b.png'>'",
                ':heart:': "'<img width='32px' height='32px' src='http://emojipedia-us.s3.amazonaws.com/cache/3e/f0/3ef0aeaf797844b672df6198c53ba479.png'>'",
                ':P': "'<img width='32px' height='32px' src='http://emojipedia-us.s3.amazonaws.com/cache/43/be/43be98eee74f44eddec9c3137b1edf28.png'>'",
                ';P': "'<img width='32px' height='32px' src='http://emojipedia-us.s3.amazonaws.com/cache/7e/d5/7ed517c9f335c3171b6f92685514667a.png'>'",
                ';+[)]': "'<img width='32px' height='32px' src='http://emojipedia-us.s3.amazonaws.com/cache/58/be/58be1ae13dbf3fb471f7f598a0365734.png'>'",
                ':+[(]': "'<img width='32px' height='32px' src='http://emojipedia-us.s3.amazonaws.com/cache/0c/04/0c04f9fd77dc486724c269587028e7d2.png'>'",
                '.-.': "'<img width='32px' height='32px' src='http://emojipedia-us.s3.amazonaws.com/cache/e6/7c/e67c860bd5cd2b9b443516171ec3c6a3.png'>'",
                '-.-': "'<img width='32px' height='32px' src='http://emojipedia-us.s3.amazonaws.com/cache/c1/05/c105ab901e2fa6e67b38879bcc0ac0b0.png'>'",
                ':pepe:': "'<img width='32px' height='32px' src='https://i.imgur.com/OE9Jb7b.png'>'"
            }
            var emval = [':D',':C','8)',':O',':)','._.',':heart:',':P',';P',';)',':(','.-.','-.-',':pepe:'];
            for(var emoticon in allreg){
            var result = new RegExp(emoticon,'g'); 
            for(var i=0;i<=13;i++){
             $(".message-text:contains('"+emval[i]+"')").html(function (_,html) {
                return html.replace(result,allreg[emoticon]);
                });
               }
            }
        }      
checkemoji();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="message-text">:D  :C :O</span>
```